# Create and use the following value-returning methods in the application

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace HospitalCharges
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public const double dailycharges = 350;

        double medcharges;
        double surgcharges;
        double labcharges;
        double phyrehab;
        double totalMiscCharges;
        double totaldailycharges;
        private object Output;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void CalcStayCharges(){

            try
            {
                double numofdays = Convert.ToDouble(txtdays);
                totaldailycharges = (double)dailycharges * numofdays;

            }
            catch { }
    }

        public void CalcMiscCharges()
        {
            try
            {
                medcharges = Convert.ToDouble(txtmedicalfee);
                surgcharges = Convert.ToDouble(txtsurgicalfee);
                labcharges = Convert.ToDouble(txtlabfee);
                phyrehab = Convert.ToDouble(txtrehabfee);

                totalMiscCharges = medcharges + surgcharges + labcharges + phyrehab;
            }
            catch { }
        }

        public void CalcTotalCharges()
        {
            double TotalCharges = totaldailycharges + totalMiscCharges;



        }

        public void BtnResult_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            CalcStayCharges();
            CalcMiscCharges();
            CalcTotalCharges();``

 Output = CalcTotalCharges();

     }      
   }
}
```

//Create and use the following value-returning methods in the application:
// CalcStayCharges – calculates and returns the base charges for the hospital //stay. This is computed as $350 times the number of days in the hospital.
// CalcMiscCharges – calculates and returns the total of the medication, //surgical, lab, and physical rehabilitation charges
// CalcTotalCharges – calculates and returns the total charges.

Comment: This smells like a homework question where you're expecting us to do it for you. Can you elaborate on the problems you're having and what you have tried? see [here for more help about asking clear questions on Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: im having problem converting the textboxes to take in the input as double...........and i don't know if the questions wants me to pass in parameters and return the values..........this is as far as i have gone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're missing the property for your arguments. Assuming the arguments in your `Convert.To()` are textBox controls, just add `.Text` next to their names to grab their text values. Return their values to a label, textBox or MessageBox. I'll go with a label for this example.

Create a label named "lbloutput" as requested by OP.

```
    double medcharges;
    double surgcharges;
    double labcharges;
    double phyrehab;
    double totalMiscCharges;
    double totaldailycharges;
    double TotalCharges
    .
    .
    .
    public void CalcStayCharges()
    {
        try
        {
            double numofdays = Convert.ToDouble(txtdays.Text);
            totaldailycharges = (double)dailycharges * numofdays;
        }
        catch { }
    }

    public void CalcMiscCharges()
    {
        try
        {
            medcharges = Convert.ToDouble(txtmedicalfee.Text);
            surgcharges = Convert.ToDouble(txtsurgicalfee.Text);
            labcharges = Convert.ToDouble(txtlabfee.Text);
            phyrehab = Convert.ToDouble(txtrehabfee.Text);

            totalMiscCharges = medcharges + surgcharges + labcharges + phyrehab;
        }
        catch { }
    }

    public void CalcTotalCharges()
    {
        TotalCharges = totaldailycharges + totalMiscCharges;
    }

    public void BtnResult_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (TextBox txt in Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
        {
            if (txt.Text == "")
            {
                txt.Text = "0";
            }
        }
        CalcStayCharges();
        CalcMiscCharges();
        CalcTotalCharges();
        lbloutput.Text = "Your total charges are: " + TotalCharges.ToString("C");
    }
```

Comment: thanks.......what of how to create those mehods and return their values like in the question?

Comment: Uh, your methods are present. The values are being returned when you click the button _btnResult._ Assign their values to a label or textBox if you wish. As for your object `Output` I can't really say what's going on there.

Comment: Did you write this code or have it assigned as homework?

Comment: can u give me an exam of how i can display it to a label.......lets say the label name is lbloutput

Comment: If the answer solved your question, please click the check beside the answer to close the case. Thank you.

Comment: blResult.Text = "Your total charges are: " + TotalCharges.ToString("C");  this line is not working

Comment: its saying totalcharges does not exist in the current context

Comment: @jeff300 Oh, declare TotalCharges under your `Initialize Component` and remove the declaration in the method `CalcTotalCharges().` I'll post the edit.

Comment: lblResult is not showing options to make it lblResult.Text

Comment: @jeff300 That doesn't sound right if it is a label. The example was updated with your requested example name; _lbloutput_.

Comment: It doesn't matter what the label name is.... The problem now is that it doesn't want me to add  .text...... You know it has intellisense  .text is not among

Comment: The result is displaying $0.0

Comment: @jeff300 You will get a 0 if you don't enter anything in a textBox. Did you get a 0 with all your textBoxes containing **explicity** numbers?
I tried it and it works: http://prntscr.com/bicm2q

Comment: @jeff300 I included something special in your button and now, if you leave textboxes blank, they will autonomously assume to 0.